# Programmatically get function app url from event grid triggered function

Tags: azure, http, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

In an HTTP triggered azure function we can get the url as follows

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext executionContext, ILogger log)
{
    string url = req.Scheme + "://" + req.Host + $"/api/AnotherFunctionOnTheApp";
}
```

But how do we do it in an event grid triggered function where we do not have the HTTPRequest object?

```
public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
{
    
}
```

The objective is to call an HTTP triggered function on the same functionapp from the event grid triggered function.

Comment: Any update? Can my answer answered your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example to get the url of the httptrigger:

```
string url = "https://" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME") + "/api/AnotherFunctionOnTheApp";
```

(Azure will offer a secure domain by default. So we can use 'https'.)

Comment: Thanks, this works. Only difference is I am using 
#if DEBUG
          string httpScheme = "http://";
#else
          string httpScheme = "https://";
#endif

So that postman call the function locally for debugging.